# How do I calculate the running total from the "total" column with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

```
DECLARE
    @start AS date = '2016-09-01 00:00:00',
    @end   AS date = '2016-09-01 23:59:00'

SELECT
   CAST( je.RefDate AS date ) RefDate,
   ChartOfAccounts.AcctName,   
   LEFT( ChartOfAccounts.FormatCode , 5 ) + '-+substring(ChartOfAccounts.FormatCode,6,2)+'-'+right(ChartOfAccounts.FormatCode,3) GLFormatCode, 
   txn.linememo, 
   txn.Debit - txn.Credit AS DebitCredit
FROM 
   Yapstone..JDT1 txn with (nolock)
   INNER JOIN Yapstone..OJDT JE with (nolock) ON JE.transid = txn.TransId
   INNER JOIN Yapstone..OACT ChartOfAccounts with (nolock) ON ChartOfAccounts.AcctCode = txn.Account
   LEFT JOIN Yapstone..orct Incoming with (nolock) ON txn.TransId = Incoming.TransId
   LEFT JOIN Yapstone..ovpm Outgoing with (nolock) ON txn.TransId = Outgoing.TransId
WHERE 
   JE.RefDate BETWEEN @start AND DATEADD( s, -1, DATEADD( d, 1, CAST(@end AS datetime ) ) )
   AND
   ChartOfAccounts.Segment_0 = 11600
```

Results from Query:

```
2016-09-01  Prepaid Expense (Yap, Yap)  11600-01-000    A/P Invoices - VLinkedIn    20258.750000

2016-09-01  Prepaid Expense (Yap, Yap)  11600-01-000    To correct: Appriver Sept invoice was booked in Au  -11084.250000
```

HELP: **How do I add a running total that starts from the beginning of time to see the impact of each one of these transactions?**

Comment: All of those `with (nolock)` hints looks cargo-cultish. Are you absolutely certain you need to include those?

Comment: @Dai Yes, I was instructed by my manager to do so